# How are the big buttons in the "Windows Activation" window called?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, forms, winforms

I'm trying to add those big buttons to my project.

How are they called? Are they even part of .NET Framework?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for WPF or Winforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find much, but I was able to find a guide on how to make a  [Windows Aero Style Wizard Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87738/C-Windows-Aero-Style-Wizard-Control) which suggests that this style isn't easily accessible in .NET. I think you should check it out and see if there is anything you'd want to use.

> As (as far as I know) there are no resources built into the .NET Framework for creating Windows Aero style forms easily, the aim of this project was to provide access to a (or some) classes that the user can use to create themed forms easily.

Comment: Thx, that's something actually :-) Maybe that's coming later ;)